# Dashed-styled list linking divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know exactly how to name this or how to explain it, so I'll give you some examples of what I have and what I want to create...

I have a list of divs, all of them with an own style, in a way that they look as Forums and sub-forums... Here I'll show a picture of what I have:

[image: What I have]

The code is simple:

```
<div id="Forums">
    <div class="category">Category</div>
    <div class="forum">Forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="forum">Forum</div>
</div>
```

And the css is also very easy:

```
.category {
    width: 95%;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: rgba(46, 183, 255, 0.67);
    margin: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.forum {
    width: auto;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: rgba(30, 101, 141, 0.67);
    border: dotted;
    margin-left: 4em;
}

.sub-forum {
    width: auto;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: rgba(12, 50, 69, 0.67);
    border: dotted;
    margin-left: 7em;
}
```

I was thinking of making a design so the categories, the forums and sub-forums are linked with a dashed-styled "list"... I don't know how to describe it, so I've made a blueprint:

[image: What I want]

Is it possible to acquire this? How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You should try and take a look into pseudo elements.

Comment: it can be achieved yes, but not with your current html structure. you must first understand, that css is not a programming language, its a styling markup. as danny suggested, you need to do it with pseudo elements `:after` and `:before` but since css is unable to determine the length of your list, you will need to hardcode it

Comment: Mmmm thanks! I've had a look into pseudo elements, but do I have to add an image or something?

Comment: not necessarily, you can simply make divs with a dashed border and put them behind your list items, hold on ill make an example

Comment: Well, if there's some js I think it won't be bad! Hahahah

Comment: Yep of course, let's try it!

Comment: here, if your list is dynamic, you must use javascript. if it is static however, you can hardcode it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/7VPNJ/

Comment: @Banana Oh thanks, it looks very good! But I didn't think about the dynamic part... Of course because there are more categories and Forums... But the idea would be like that, it looks so great!

Comment: @Banana - You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Jared Farrish i would but unfortunately it wont work with dynamic list so its not really an answer :(

Comment: @Banana - The question doesn't explicitly state a "dynamic" solution is required; someone could just as easily generate markup that incorporates your approach into classes. Post it as an answer, it's alright. `;)`

Comment: You saw it? Opened jsfiddle? Do you like it? :D

Comment: http://odyniec.net/articles/turning-lists-into-trees/ Pure CSS solution. Requires an image and is designed for UL > LI not tables, bit may be able to be adapted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Dynamic CSS only solution

First, this involves markup modifications for two reasons :

**1. HTML Semantics**

Your content is organized in herachy, `category > forum > sub forum` (like a menu) so to follow HTML semanitcs you need to use nested lists `ul > li > ul > li ...`

**2. Styling**

Changing the markup to nested elements will alow you to target last and first elements of each level with the `:last-child` and `:first-child` pseudo selectors and style them accordingly.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/4cD2R/)

*HTML :*

```
<ul id="Forums">
    <li class="category"><div>Category</div>
        <ul>
            <li class="forum"><div>Forum</div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</li>
                    <li class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</li>
                    <li class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="forum"><div>Forum</div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="category"><div>Category</div>
    </li>
    <li class="category"><div>Category</div>
        <ul>
            <li class="forum"><div>Forum</div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</li>
                    <li class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="forum"><div>Forum</div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</li>
                    <li class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
             <li class="forum"><div>Forum</div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</li>
                    <li class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

*CSS :*

```
ul, li{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
.category > div{
    width: 95%; height: 3em;
    background-color: rgba(46, 183, 255, 0.67);
}
.forum {
    margin-left: 2em;
}
.forum > div, .sub-forum{
    height: 3em;
    border: dotted;
}
.forum > div{    
    background-color: rgba(30, 101, 141, 0.67);
}
.sub-forum {
    margin-left: 3em;
    background-color: rgba(12, 50, 69, 0.67);
}
.category li:before, .forum:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    right:100%;
    border-bottom: 0.2em dotted;
}
.category .forum:before{
    top:-1.5em; 
    height:100%; width:1em;
    border-left: 0.2em dotted;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.forum:last-child:before{
    height:3em;    
}
.forum:first-child:before{
    top:0;
    bottom:1.5em;    
}
.forum:after{
    top:1.5em;
    width:1.2em;
}
.sub-forum:before{
    bottom:50%;
    width:3.5em; height: 100%;
    border-left: 0.2em dotted;
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see the answer! Thank you for the CSS only solution, I'm implementing it in my page and it seems to work fine, I think I'll use it! :D

Answer (score 2):

If the to-be style list is dynamic, you will have to involve JavaScript for the simple reason that css is not a programming language, it is a styling markup and is not suitable/designed to handle dynamic html elements.

In any case, the requested styling can be achieved using the css3 pseudo elements **[:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter)** and **[:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore)**

what those selectors do, is pretty simple. they add another dynamic `<span>` before/after the selected element. for example:

```
.myElement:after{

}
```

will add a dynamic element right after ***the content*** of `.myElement`

the styling of the :before/:after elements is the same as any other element, with the exclusion of the `content` attribute that decides what to put inside the newly created element, in most cases you would want to put nothing ('') aka blank content;

in your example list, it can be styled by inserting a `:before` span with a styled left border, behind the list items:

```
.category {
    width: 95%;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: rgba(46, 183, 255, 0.67);
    margin: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.forum {
    width: auto;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: rgba(30, 101, 141, 0.67);
    border: dotted;
    margin-left: 4em;
}

.sub-forum {
    width: auto;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: rgba(12, 50, 69, 0.67);
    border: dotted;
    margin-left: 7em;
}
.sub-forum:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:3.6em;
    border:4px dotted black; 
    height:3em;
    margin-left:-4em;
    margin-top:-1.5em;
    border-top:none;
    border-right:none;
    z-index:-2;
}

.forum:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:1em;
    border:4px dotted black; 
    height:15em;
    margin-left:-1.6em;
    margin-top:-13.5em;
    border-top:none;
    border-right:none;
    z-index:-2;
}
.forum:nth-of-type(2):before{
    height:1.5em;
    margin-top:0em;
}
```

Live example: <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/7VPNJ/)**</kbd>

note that the position of the new elements has to be absolute, or they will push everything down.

in case of a dynamic list, you will have to utilize JavaScript to create dynamic elements using the above styling per list item.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! Now I truly understand how it works... Thanks a lot, it was what I wanted. Well, I didn't think about the dynamic part, so I'll have a look and I'll try to see if I find something for doing it dynamic. Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 2):

This is a javascript solution for **dynamic** list.

### What I changed in original list:

- removed alpha from list items ("categories", "forums" and "sub-forums")
- changed text color of "forums" and "sub-forums" to white for readability

### Notes

- *forums* **are expected** to be placed in *categories*
- *sub-forums* **are expected** to be placed in *forums*

<sup>Nothing is drawn if you violate above rules</sup>

- categories and forums **can** contain no childs, it is not a problem (as you can see in my example list)

---

## HTML (try to edit it in fiddle or somewhere else to add or remove new items!)

```
<div id="Forums">
    <div class="category">Category</div>
    <div class="forum">Forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="forum">Forum</div>
    <div class="forum">Forum</div>
    <div class="forum">Forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="forum">Forum</div>
    <div class="category">Category</div>
    <div class="forum">Forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="sub-forum">Sub-forum</div>
    <div class="forum">Forum</div>
    <div class="category">Category</div>
    <div class="forum">Forum</div>
</div>
```

## CSS (don't change default items margins by the way):

```
.category {
    width: 95%;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: rgba(46, 183, 255, 1);
    margin: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.forum {
    width: auto;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: rgba(30, 101, 141, 1);
    color:white;
    border: dotted;
    margin-left: 4em;
}

.sub-forum {
    width: auto;
    height: 3em;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color: rgba(12, 50, 69, 1);
    border: dotted;
    margin-left: 7em;
}
```

## Javascript

```
var borderWidth = "4px";
var borderColor = "black";

for (var forum = 0; forum < document.getElementsByClassName("forum").length; forum++) {
    var rect = document.createElement("div");
    rect.style.margin = "2.5em";
    rect.style.border = "dotted";
    rect.style.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    rect.style.borderColor = borderColor;
    rect.style.position = "absolute";

    if (document.getElementsByClassName("forum")[forum].previousElementSibling.className == "category") {
        rect.style.top = document.getElementsByClassName("forum")[forum].previousElementSibling.offsetTop - 10 + "px";
        rect.style.height = document.getElementsByClassName("forum")[forum].offsetTop - document.getElementsByClassName("forum")[forum].previousElementSibling.offsetTop - 2 + "px";
    } else {
        rect.style.top = document.getElementsByClassName("forum")[forum - 1].offsetTop - 10 + "px";
        rect.style.height = document.getElementsByClassName("forum")[forum].offsetTop - document.getElementsByClassName("forum")[forum - 1].offsetTop - 2 + "px";
    }

    rect.style.width = "100px";
    rect.style.zIndex = "-1";
    document.body.appendChild(rect);
}

for (var subforum = 0; subforum < document.getElementsByClassName("sub-forum").length; subforum++) {

    var rect = document.createElement("div");
    rect.style.margin = "2.5em";
    rect.style.marginLeft = "5em"
    rect.style.border = "dotted";
    rect.style.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    rect.style.borderColor = borderColor;
    rect.style.position = "absolute";

    rect.style.top = document.getElementsByClassName("sub-forum")[subforum].previousElementSibling.offsetTop - 10 + "px";
    rect.style.height = document.getElementsByClassName("sub-forum")[subforum].offsetTop - document.getElementsByClassName("sub-forum")[subforum].previousElementSibling.offsetTop - 2 + "px";

    rect.style.width = "100px";
    rect.style.zIndex = "-1";
    document.body.appendChild(rect);
    document.getElementsByClassName("sub-forum")[subforum].nextElementSibling.className;
}
```

## JSFiddle

If anyone wanna test it, [there is it](http://jsfiddle.net/EaN3G/3/) and [fullscreen version](http://jsfiddle.net/EaN3G/3/embedded/result/).

If something is bad with width, change the border width

```
var borderWidth="4px";
```

or color

```
var borderColor="black";
```

Comment: Oh my god... It's just... Amazing! I didn't expect anybody to do that... Thanks a lot, you just saved my life! Seriously thanks a lot for making the code for me... I was really lost about doing it, I'm not so good at JavaScript... Well, you saved me, thanks another time! :D

Comment: @peregraum Glad to help! As I promised. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which uses pure CSS and does not rely on fixed heights or anything like that.  I also want to say that if you could alter your markup to represent a nested structure, this would be a whole lot easier... just sayin':

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/EaN3G/4/

```
.forum,
.sub-forum {
    position: relative;
}

.forum:before,
.forum:after,
.sub-forum:before,
.sub-forum:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.5em;
    top: -55%;
    bottom: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.forum:before,
.sub-forum:before {
    border-left: 3px dotted #000;
}
.sub-forum:before {
    left: -4.5em;
    width: 3em;
    border-right: 3px dotted #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.forum:after,
.sub-forum:after {
    width: 1.5em;
    border-bottom: 3px dotted #f00;
}
```

Comment: there is an issue here : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/EaN3G/8/, nested structure seems necessary for  a dynamic CSS only solution...

Comment: It appears you are correct sir.  Thanks for pointing that out.